# Infinite σ-algebra strictly contains another infinite σ-algebra

Tags: measure-theory

I'm trying to prove that infinite σ-algebra has infinite number of disjoint sets. As a first step , I want to show that every infinite σ-algebra strictly contains another infinite σ-algebra. Here is my "proof":

Let $\Sigma$ be infinite sigma algebra on $X$. Let $A\in \Sigma$ such that $A \neq X, \emptyset $.

Denote: $\Sigma_A = \{ A\cap x | x \in \Sigma \}$, $\Sigma_{A^c} = \{ A^c\cap x | x \in \Sigma \}$.

I want to prove that at least one of them is infinite sigma algebra, but I'm not sure how to prove that at least one of them is infinite.

Is the following argument valid?

$\Sigma \subset \Sigma_{A^c} \cup \Sigma_A  \implies |\Sigma| \leq|\Sigma_{A^c}|\cdot|\Sigma_A|$, therefore at least one of the sets must be infinite.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $\Sigma_A$ and $\Sigma_{A^{c}}$ are both finite then $\Sigma_A \times \Sigma_{A^{c}}$ is finite. The map $x \to (x\cap A,x\cap A^{c})$ is one-to-one so that will force $\Sigma$ itself to be finite.